# Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\OSPanel\domains\PHP\07\7\pass.php on line 15 В чем ошибка

Tags: php

```
<?php


$link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $dbName);
session_start();

if ($_SESSION['auth']) {//4
    $login = $_SESSION['user']; 
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE login='$login'";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $query, $user);
$user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $hash = $user['password'];

if(!empty($_POST['old-pass']) && !empty($_POST['new-pass'])) {
        if(password_verify($_POST['old-pass'], $hash)) {
            if($_POST['old-pass'] != $_POST['new-pass']) {
                if(strlen($_POST['new-pass']) > 6 || strlen($_POST['new-pass']) < 12) {
                    $new_pass_hash = password_hash($_POST['new-pass'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
                    $query = "UPDATE users SET password='$new_pass_hash' WHERE login='$login'";
                    mysqli_query($link, $query);
                    header('Location: profile.php');
                } 
                else {
                    echo "Пароль должен содержать от 6 до 12 символов";
                }
            } 
            else {
                echo "Новый и старый пароль совпадают";
            }
        }
         else {
            echo "Текущий пароль введен неверно";
        }
    }
```

Comment: [возможные дубликаты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bphp%5d%20boolean%20given&searchOn=3)

Comment: `expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given` -- ошибка в этом.

Comment: $result у тебя boolean. О чём, собственно, ошибка и говорит

Comment: mysqli_fetch_assoc здесь не на 15 строчке